# Уменьшение сложности алгоритма

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, reactjs, оптимизация, сложность

Всем привет!

Прошу помощи в понимании как правильно оценить и, самое главное, уменьшить сложность алгоритма.

Проблема - тормозит анимация интерфейса на React при обращении к базе на одном из легаси проектов.
При анализе обнаружил большую задержку при отрисовке полученных данных в таблицу.

В выделенном комментариями куске делается сначала .map, внутри ещё один .map, внутри еще .find, да еще и несколько indexOf. Сложность алгоритма, если я правильно понимаю, точно не меньше O(n^2) (а скорее всего больше).

В сети полно информации про определении сложности алгоритмов, но понятной информации по уменьшению  этой самой сложности я не нашел.
Каким образом можно оптимизировать данный алгоритм? Какие вообще существуют принципы уменьшения сложности?

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

```
                <Table className="YearShedule" striped bordered size="sm">
                  <tbody>

// НАЧАЛО АЛГОРИТМА
                    {monthOrder.map((mName) => (
                      <tr className="YS_row" key={monthOrder.indexOf(mName)}>
                        <td>{monthRusName[mName]}</td>

                        {daysOfMonth.map((d) => {
                          let day_params = this.state.plc.shedule.base.days.find(
                            (el) => el.date == monthOrder.indexOf(mName) + 1 + ':' + d
                          )

                          let ind = this.state.plc.shedule.base.days.indexOf(day_params)
//КОНЕЦ АЛГОРИТМА

                          return day_params ? (
                            <DayShedule
                              key={d}
                              day_params={day_params}
                              title_mn={monthRusName[mName]}
                              title_d={d}
                              changeShedule={(val) => (this.state.plc.shedule.base.days[ind] = val)}
                            />
                          ) : (
                            <td key={d}>
                              <b>{d}</b>
                              <br />
                              &nbsp;
                              <br />
                              &nbsp;
                            </td>
                          )
                        })}
                      </tr>
                    ))}
                  </tbody>
                </Table>
```

Comment: Вы бы пример данных привели и что у вас this.state.plc.shedule.base.days ну и что требуется сделать. А по уменьшению сложности - надо придумать алгоритм который не будет делать IndexOf. Например заранее пробежаться по массивам (или в том же проходе) и сделать из них словари вроде `dict={mName1: first_index1, mName2:...}` и тогда брать по словарю уже `dict[mName]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Боже. Приведу исправленный кусок Вашего кода

```
{monthOrder.map((mName, i) => (
                  <tr className="YS_row" key={i}>
                    <td>{monthRusName[mName]}</td>

                    {daysOfMonth.map((d) => {
                      let ind = this.state.plc.shedule.base.days.findIndex(
                        (el) => el.date == i + 1 + ':' + d
                      )

                      let day_params = this.state.plc.shedule.base.days[ind]
//КОНЕЦ АЛГОРИТМА

                      return day_params ? (
```

Comment: спасибо. Таким образом мы избавились от лишних IndexOf. А как быть с остальными вложенными циклами? Правильно ли я понимаю, что основная нагрузка именно из-за них?

Comment: скорее всего нагрузка из-за перерисовок